# Exception in sending emails from java application : Relaying denied

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail, emailrelay

We are using Spring Mail to send emails from java application
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl

Spring Email Configuration is

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" autowire-candidate="default">
        <property name="host" value="${test.email.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${test.email.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${test.email.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${test.email.password}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Java code snapshot is

```
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("errorMessageMailSender")
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;

    ..............
    ..............

          try {
                MimeMessage mailMessage = buildEmailMimeMessage(properties,mimeMultipart);
                logger.info(String.format("Built MimeMessage object is <%s>",mailMessage));
                if (mailMessage != null) {
                    mailSender.send(mailMessage);
                    logger.info("Mail sent Successfully");
                }else{
                    logger.info("Mail send failed as Mail message object construction failed.");
                }
                result=true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("An exception occurred while sending mail :: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Property files

```
test.email.host=mail.mydomain.net
test.email.port=2525
test.email.username=demo@mydomain.net
test.email.password=mypassword
```

But we are below exception, and email is not being sent

```
An exception occurred while sending mail :: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 <demo@mydomain.net>... Relaying denied
```

Comment: Check http://www.gammadyne.com/relaying_denied.htm, google's first result

Comment: This is an SMTP problem, not a Java problem...

Comment: if I keep my username and password properties as blank, will smtp auth property set to true, will cause this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smtp server that you are trying to send the mail to is rejecting to relay. If it is your own local server that is not a problem, you may change configurations to relay mails from your mydomain.net . But if it is an external server (gmail for example), you have to use a real registered domain.

To test your code against a mail server, I recommend you to setup a dockerized Apache James Server, create some test users on it and send and receive emails.

Answer (score 2):

This JavaMail FAQ entry should help:

- [When I try to send a message, why do I get javax.mail.SendFailedException: 550 Unable to relay for my-address?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#norelay)

Answer (score 1):

Working code,

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class JavaEmail {

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        JavaEmail javaEmail = new JavaEmail();

        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
        javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
        javaEmail.sendEmail();
    }

    public void setMailServerProperties() {

        String emailPort = "587";//gmail's port

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    }

    public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {
        String[] toEmails = { "enter to mail ids" };
        String emailSubject = "Java Email";
        String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
        }

        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
        //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String fromUser = "enter from Id";//ignore gmail domain
        String fromUserEmailPassword = "enter password";

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, your emailservice has to be inside of your production sphere. you cannot hit prod smtp server from outside of that sphere. at least that was the case with the issue that I encountered.